# Python property and __dict__ method

Tags: python

consider this class:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, name = 'hi'):
        self._name = name
    def getname(self):
        return self._name
    def setname(self, value):
        self._name = value
    name =  property(getname, setname)
a = A('hello')
```

> > a.name  will give me 'hello'

However, i noticed that, `a.__dict__['name'] = 'something'`,  and the instance var. 'name' was reset.
Eg. `a.__dict__['_name'] = {'animal' : 'tiger'}` and `a.name` resulted in `{'animal' : 'tiger'}`.

I was wondering can anybody use something same/similar to corrupt the instance variable's value to anything, just by accessing the `__dict__` magic method of that particular object? Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 3):

Sure.  Someone could also do this:

```
a._name = {'animal': 'tiger'}
```

Or, you know, they could just edit your source code.

Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

Python does not offer protection for your data from other code running in the same process.  There are no private attributes, and so on.  Python provides structures that you can use in conventional idiomatic ways, but there's nothing a language can do to protect you from your coworkers.